# How can we detect that the current view is out of visibility due to scrolling?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-drawable, android-viewholder

For a recycler view the holder pattern is being used for efficiency.
As we scroll a recycler list, as items as shown views are created or reused.
My question is: if an item is scrolled out of visibility and the corresponding view is not visible is there any method called that indicates this? E.g. if we are downloading a resource in a view and we need to cancel the download as the user scrolls the view, is that done automatically or is there some method call we need to implement on the ViewHolder or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You could override this `RecyclerView` method to check when item is being recycled.

```
    @Override 
    public void onViewRecycled(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder);
        // check if download is in progress and stop it.
    }
```

> Called when a view created by this adapter has been recycled.
>
> A view is recycled when a RecyclerView.LayoutManager decides that it
>   no longer needs to be attached to its parent RecyclerView. This can be
>   because it has fallen out of visibility or a set of cached views
>   represented by views still attached to the parent RecyclerView. If an
>   item view has large or expensive data bound to it such as large
>   bitmaps, this may be a good place to release those resources.
>
> RecyclerView calls this method right before clearing ViewHolder's
>   internal data and sending it to RecycledViewPool. This way, if
>   ViewHolder was holding valid information before being recycled, you
>   can call getAdapterPosition() to get its adapter position.

Comment: There's also `onViewDetached(ViewHolder)` method which is called at the exact moment viewholder leaves the viewport, but it does not imply it will be recycled so it's not a good place to interrupt async tasks.